# TS: Set type for `this` in a decorator

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

When I set `strict` mode in `tsconfig` file I got the issue related to the type of `this` in my decorators, e.g the hint I see:

`TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.`

`Infer 'this' type of 'SyncTimer' from usage`

[image: Infer 'this' type of 'SyncTimer' from usage]

And here how does it solve after  - it's strange

[image]

How to solve this issue in the `strict` mode properly?

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Comment: Where do you declare `logger` value for this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code gives you an error because the keyword `this` can refer to any type of Object.

As you are using an export function, when you import this function in another class called `B`, it will be considered as a part of `B`, so when you are calling your function through an instance of `B` called `bObj`, the keyword `this` will refer to `bObj`, and not to the instance of the A class in which you originally declared your function.

Comment: "*when you import this function in another class, let's call it B, it will be considered as a part of B, so the keyword this will refer to the current B instance*". That's not necessarily true. It depends on *how* the function is executed. The value of `this` is determined at call time for normal functions. [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)

Comment: Sure, I assumed that the function was called from an instance of the B class. I will edit my answer to be more clear.